# Dynamically sorting a NamedQuery? Seam/Hibernate/JPA

Tags: hibernate, sorting, jpa, seam

I have several `NamedQuery`'s defined, and I'd like to be able to sort on a field for an entity dynamically, without having to create unique `NamedQuery`'s for each field I want to sort on.  For example:

I have an entity called MyObject, with fields 'a', 'b', and 'c'.  My base query is "`SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObject o`", but I'd like to be able to add an `ORDER BY` clause to my query.  Ideally, I'd be able to do something like named parameters, where my query would look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObject o ORDER BY :order
```

I would then specify the field (a, b, c) that I want to sort on.  Is there any way to accomplish this using Seam/Hibernate/JPA?  Is there a better strategy for tackling this?

Comment: This question is related to [Hibernate named query order by parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120388/hibernate-named-query-order-by-partameter). Maybe the corresponding answer help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Named queries cannot be changed at run-time.

//----- Edited-part

```
public void getOrders(String orderByElement){

    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObject o ORDER BY " + orderByElement;

    entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Its JPA specific.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  But, would the query you provided work if I specified it as a JPA @NamedQuery?  Or would it only work when created with entityManager.createQuery?  I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't, but just want to make sure.

Comment: I don't think this solution works. According to the [JPQL Language reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_input_params) input parameters are only allowed in `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses. Have you tried that query?

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay, that said, does this have an impact on performance?  I believe I recall reading something that said that NamedQuery's have better performance than creating a Query on the fly.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it gives better performance. Named queries are validated during deployment time & query definition is parsed only once and re-used afterwards. Deployment can fail if query is syntactically incorrect. They are scoped to the persistence unit.

Comment: On a side-note: if you use this solution in a website it'll be easy to hack using a simple SQL-injection. There's no other solution for dynamical Hibernate queries afaik so this is the correct solution, but add a method to check whether it's a valid argument and reject strings containing a 'select' or other suspicious SQL statements...

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection. It should not be done this way.

Comment: @RudiKershaw Can you revert correct way to accomplish it; would appreciate criticism with corrections.

Comment: @NayanWadekar there's no way to do it by altering a string query. Would either have to create your query programatically using the Criteria API, or build options into you query using case statements as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448635/2182928.

Answer (score 3):

See my solution in [hibernate-named-query-order-by-partameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120388/hibernate-named-query-order-by-partameter)

Basic idea is to store the query without the 'order by clause and edit it on at run-time.