# JPA: NamedQuery parameter in query string for switches

Tags: java, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I wondered how to do in JPA if I want to call a `NamedQuery` stored in a entity with different settings for example for order DESC or ASC to use in a way like for parameters (`setParameter()`). For example this is not working:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Entry.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE e.switch = :switch ORDER BY e.name :order)
```

Is really the only way to use two queries like:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Entry.findAllDESC", query = "SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE e.switch = :switch ORDER BY e.name DESC)
@NamedQuery(name = "Entry.findAllASC", query = "SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE e.switch = :switch ORDER BY e.name ASC)
```

or to generate the query string in code?

I wondered that I found no way, because in most queries I have to change such things and this would make a programming style where I prefer to use central `NamedQueries` stored in the entities nearly impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate + answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120388/hibernate-named-query-order-by-partameter

Answer (score 0):

`NamedQuery` is static query. You can't put dynamic query value (i.e ASC or DESC) in `NamedQuery`. You should use `DynamicQuery`(i.e. JPQL) or `Native Query` or `Criteria` to get your desired output.