# Placeholder for JPQL comparison operators

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I'm new to JPA (JPQL), so I got stacked with no good solution to maintain WHERE clause with a flexible comparison plan.
I would like to implement a JPQL statement of the form like:

```
SELECT i FROM Item i 
    WHERE i.weight (comparison_operator_placeholder) :weight
        AND i.height (comparison_operator_placeholder) :height;

(comparison_operator_placeholder):{ = | < | > | <= | >= }
```

The (comparison_operator_placeholder) shall be selected during runtime, based on user's input.
Intuitively I realize that no such grammar exists, however, there shall be other way than writing queries for each combination. I will appreciate any workaround.

Comment: Be careful: you mixup the concept of "wildcard" (typically `%`, `_` or maybe `*`) with comparison operators. This might be misleading and misunderstood by other programmers. What you're actually looking for is "dynamic", I guess.

Comment: Can you show us the Java code logic which would determine the type of comparison you intend to do in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: you're missing "<>" btw

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write multiple queries.  Just use a variable for the operator(s), like so:

```
String query = "SELECT i FROM Item i \n" +
                "WHERE i.weight " + operator + " :weight \n" +
                "AND i.height " + operator2 + " :height";
```

Comment: probably I was not very clear at description. Your solution is fine, but I was thinking about '@NamedQuery'. So I wanted to annotate an entity with a query like your, but it will not work in such case.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167730/dynamic-named-query-in-entity-class-using-jpql-example