# Hibernate NamedQuery two parameters

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create NamedQuery like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Advertisement.getBySubcategoryList, query = "From Advertisement where subcategoryId IN (:subcategoryId) order by :sort :order "),
```

But on IDE i see error, that i cant set parameter after parameter: :sort :order

Do you know how to create this query ?

Thanks

StackTrace:

```
 ERROR: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000177: Error in named query: Advertisement.getBySubcategoryList
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 101 [From org.ogloszenia.app.domain.Advertisement where subcategoryId IN (:subcategoryId) order by :sort :order ]
```

Comment: Please share full stacktrace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Named Query Order By parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120388/hibernate-named-query-order-by-parameter)

Comment: not supported for that you have create query and concat the sortBy to that query