# "Spring Data JPA" Repository Parameter with that name did not exist although I declared it

Tags: java, spring, parameters, repository, spring-data-jpa

This is crazy I try lots of way but this is still showed up. It said that:

Parameter with that name [sortBy] did not exist.
Look, it is already there. When I try to edit the Query with AND  instead of case when, it worked but not the query I want.

My repository:

```
 @Query("SELECT u FROM CommentEntity u WHERE u.postId = :postId " +
        "order by case when (u.sentimentScore = :sortBy) " +
        "then -1 else u.sentimentScore end" )
Page<CommentEntity> findAllByPostIdwSort(@Param("postId")String postid, 
                                         @Param("sortBy")Integer sortBy, 
                                         Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: What's the JPA implementation in your project? I can reproduce this issue using Hibernate JPA. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4120388 mentions `input parameters are only allowed in the WHERE and HAVING clauses`.

Comment: Was this issue resolved, I'm facing same problem