# JPA Criteria orderBy: unexpected AST node

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have the following criteria query, which retrieves some fields from `Anfrage` and `Sparte` entities and also the translated string for the `sparte.i18nKey`.
This works as expected if I dont use `orderBy`.

Now I have the requirement to sort by the translated string for `sparte.i18nKey` and using the `orderBy` as shown below, results in `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node`

So the problem must be the subselect in the `orderBy` clause!

```
select distinct new
  my.domain.model.dto.AnfrageDTO(
      anfrage0.id,
      anfrage0.name,
      anfrage0.sparte.id,
      anfrage0.sparte.i18nKey,
      -- retrieve translated string for sparte.i18nKey
      (select rb0.value from at.luxbau.mis2.domain.model.ResourceBundleEntity as rb0
       where (anfrage0.sparte.i18nKey = rb0.key) and (rb0.language = 'de'))
  )
from my.domain.model.impl.Anfrage as anfrage0
  left join anfrage0.sparte as sparte
order by (
  -- sort by translated string for sparte.i18nKey
  select rb1.value
  from my.domain.model.ResourceBundleEntity as rb1
  where (anfrage0.sparte.i18nKey = rb1.key) and (rb1.language = 'de')
) asc
```

My Java code looks like this:

```
private List<AnfrageDTO> getAnfragen() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<AnfrageDTO> query = cb.createQuery(AnfrageDTO.class);
    Root<Anfrage> anfrage = query.from(Anfrage.class);  
    anfrage.join(Anfrage_.sparte, JoinType.LEFT);

    query.select(cb.construct(AnfrageDTO.class,
        anfrage.get(Anfrage_.id),
        anfrage.get(Anfrage_.name),
        anfrage.get(Anfrage_.sparte).get(Sparte_.id),
        anfrage.get(Anfrage_.sparte).get(Sparte_.i18nKey),
        // create subquery for translated sparte.i18nKey
        createResourceBundleSubQuery(cb, query, anfrage.get(Anfrage_.sparte).get(Sparte_.i18nKey)).getSelection()));

    TypedQuery<AnfrageDTO> tq = entityManager
            .createQuery(query)
            // use subquery to sort by translated sparte.i18nKey
            .orderBy(cb.asc(createResourceBundleSubQuery(cb, query, anfrage.get(Anfrage_.sparte).get(Sparte_.i18nKey))));

    tq.setMaxResults(10);
    List<AnfrageDTO> anfragen = tq.getResultList();
    return anfragen;
}

public Subquery<String> createResourceBundleSubQuery(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<?> query, <String> expr) {
    Subquery<String> subquery = query.subquery(String.class);
    Root<ResourceBundleEntity> rb = subquery.from(ResourceBundleEntity.class);
    subquery
        .select(rb.get(ResourceBundleEntity_.value))
        .where(cb.and(
                      cb.equal(expr, rb.get(ResourceBundleEntity_.key)),
                      cb.equal(rb.get(ResourceBundleEntity_.language), "de")));
    return subquery;
}
```

Using a native SQL query with subselect in orderBy works also as expected.

```
select distinct  
  anfrage0_.id,
  anfrage0_.name,
  anfrage0_.sparte_id,
  sparte4_.i18n_key,
  (select rb3.i18n_value from resource_bundle rb3 where rb3.language_code = 'de' and rb3.i18n_key = sparte4_.i18n_key) as sparte_i18n_value
from
  mis2.anfrage anfrage0_
  left outer join mis2.sparte sparte4_ on anfrage0_.sparte_id = sparte4_.id
order by (
  select rb.i18n_value 
  from mis2.resource_bundle rb    
  where sparte4_.i18n_key = rb.i18n_key and rb.language_code = 'de'
) asc
```

Also using an alias in the  native SQL query works also as expected.

```
select distinct  
  anfrage0_.id,
  anfrage0_.name,
  anfrage0_.sparte_id,
  sparte4_.i18n_key,
  (select rb3.i18n_value from resource_bundle rb3 where rb3.language_code = 'de' and rb3.i18n_key = sparte4_.i18n_key) as sparte_i18n_value
from
  mis2.anfrage anfrage0_
  left outer join mis2.sparte sparte4_ on anfrage0_.sparte_id = sparte4_.id
order by sparte_i18n_value
asc
```

It would be great if JPA Criteria API would support using an alias in orderBy clause!

Any hints welcome - Thank you!

My environment is WildFly 11 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: The answer depends on the JPA provider in use. Judging by the SQL generated you use Hibernate. The JPA spec does not specify the use of a SUBQUERY in the ORDER clause. Some JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus) do allow that, though yours seemingly doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't support passing parameter in order by clause, your problem has been asked before: [Hibernate Named Query Order By parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120388/hibernate-named-query-order-by-parameter)

Comment: He is using a *SUBQUERY*, not a PARAMETER in the ORDER clause. The JPA spec doesn't specify their use anywhere but WHERE/HAVING clauses yes, but it is a SUBQUERY.

Comment: Yes, both SUBQUERY and parameter make the ORDER clause dynamic in the query and the JPA doesn't support it.